# FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException when trying to link google account with new phone number

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

In my application I use Firebase to authenticate myself.

First the user is authenticated with the phone, I need to verify it, and then at the time you want, you can log in with google to have a better experience on the app...

The login in both makes it perfect, I have no problem with that, it's more, you uninstall the app, reinstall it and it's as if nothing had happened.

But the problem I have is that when the user changes his phone number and re-enters the application (eg: uninstall and reinstall) is registered with his number, then if you want to use your google account, I get this error:

**SIGN_IN**

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: This credential is already associated with a different user account.
```

**REAUTHENTICATE**

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.
```

Which is what I can do so that the user can reuse his google account with another phone until now I come erasing the old users, but it is not good that.

Or what other alternative do I have?

PS: if they say to activate multiple accounts by mail, it does not work...

Comment: Keep in mind a thing that I had to understand myself: "reauthenticate", despite the name, is never an answer for this kind of scenario.

Is intented to this situation only: you have a correctly authenticated user and need to perform some action that demand a <b>recent</b> auth (change mail, password or remove an account) but the user creation or auth is too old. So you get your current authenticated user and "reauthenticate" to allow these operations.

reauthenticate isn't useful to nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable users to have multiple accounts per email address. To enable or disable this option follow these steps:

**Step 1:**

Go to your Firebase console, choose Authentication, select the SIGN-IN METHOD tab and at the bottom of your page you'll find the Advanced section.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception only occurs when you try to link an Auth Provider that was already associated with another account. You can't avoid this exception but there are ways to handle it.

> But the problem I have is that when the user changes his phone number and re-enters the application (eg: uninstall and reinstall) is registered with his number, then if you want to use your google account

From what I understand, the user creates a new account with his new phone number and then tries to use the google account that was associated with his old phone number. This would not work because you have no way to know if user changed his phone number when he creates a new account.

One solution is to let your user sign in with his google account and then show a UI to update/add his phone number.

Alternatively, **you can catch this exception and when it occurs then show an 'update phone number' screen where user enters his/her new phone number which is then associated with his account**.

Refer to this page to get more details on how to link accounts:

[Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking)